# Number of threads required for IO bound async work

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

**TL;DR:**
Is it possible to kick off a series of IO bound tasks using only one thread using `async await`?

**In less brief:**
Trying to learn `async await`. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8v5EQRfQaA) ("Async Best Practices for C# and Visual Basic"), the speaker gives an example of using `async await` to kick off some IO bound work. He explicitly says (at 21m 40s) whilst explaining why parallel for loops are not optimal as they use up loads of threads:

> We don't need more threads for this. We don't need two threads...

Can we really kick off multiple requests asyncronously without using more than one thread? How? Unfortunately, the speaker didn't provide all the code so here's my stab at it:

```
// Pretty much exactly the same as video
private async Task<List<string>> LoadHousesAsync()
{
    // Running on the UI thread
    Debug.Print("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Task<string> t = LoadHouseAsync(i);
        tasks.Add(t);
    }

    string[] loadedHouses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return loadedHouses.ToList();
}

// My guess of the LoadHouseAsync method
private Task<string> LoadHouseAsync(int i)
{
    // Running on the UI thread
    Debug.Print("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return Task.Run(() => LoadHouse(i));
}

// My guess of the LoadHouse method
private string LoadHouse(int i)
{
    // **** This is on a different thread  :(  ****
    Debug.Print("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate I/O bound work
    return "House" + i;
}
```

Here's the output.

```
Thread: 10
Thread: 10
Thread: 3
Thread: 10
Thread: 10
Thread: 11
Thread: 10
Thread: 12
Thread: 10
Thread: 13
Thread: 14
```

Comment: None of your code is even close to simulating IO Threads, because IO threads are not managed by .Net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with async I/O. What you made is a very nice example of doing it wrong (unfortunately, it's also quite common).

[`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) runs a method on a thread pool thread, [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) blocks the thread. So your example simulates doing synchronous (blocking) I/O on multiple threads.

To correctly perform async I/O, you need to use async methods all the way down. Never use `Task.Run` for I/O. You can simulate an asynchronous I/O method using [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private async Task<string> LoadHouseAsync(int i)
{
    Debug.Print("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Delay(5000); // simulate async I/O bound work
    return "House" + i;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `Task.Delay` is the only way to simulate an IO call because it doesn't use a thread.

Comment: I would use `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("google.com")`. It doesn't simulate I/O, but it works :).

Answer (score 0):

> Can we really kick off multiple requests asyncronously without using more than one thread?

Yes, here is a real world example (pseudo asp.net-mvc and entity framework, where EF will make IO calls to Sql Server for example).

```
public async ActionResult()
{
  var model = new Company();

  using (var db1 = new DbContext)
  using (var db2 = new DbContext)
  {
    var task1 = db1.Employees.ToListAsync();
    var task2 = db1.Managers.ToListAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

    model.employees = task1.Result;
    model.managers = task2.Result;
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I realized I didn't write it correctly, still working on it.. that is absolutely not what it should do.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Why don't you just await it then instead of `Task.Result`? I really don't like Task.Result, too dangerous in my opinion.

Comment: I mean `model.Employees = await task1; model.Managers = await task2;` If you want parallel programming, this is the way I tend to do it. Task.Result has the possibility of a synchronous block, which is in theory impossible with your code. This way its inherently safe, rather than structurally safe.

Comment: Erik, I am curious, are you saying the second Task for Managers will be awaited before the first await is finished?

Comment: Yes that is what happens.